# Plot predicted values on true data time serie using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, keras

I am trying to replicate Siraj's code for predicting stock prices in R (https://github.com/llSourcell/How-to-Predict-Stock-Prices-Easily-Demo).

This is my code:

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llSourcell/How-to-Predict-Stock-Prices-Easily-Demo/master/sp500.csv"
sp500 <- read.csv(url, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(sp500) <- "closingPrice"

# choose sequence length
seq_length <- 50
sequence_length <- seq_length + 1
result <- list()
for (i in 1:(nrow(sp500) - seq_length)){
  result[[i]] <- sp500[i : (i + seq_length),1]
}

# normalised data
normalised_data <- list()
for (i in 1:length(result)){
  normalised_window <- ((result[[i]] / result[[i]][[1]]) - 1)
  normalised_data[[i]] <- normalised_window
}
result <- normalised_data

# test <- do.call(rbind, result)
# define train and test datasets
row <- round(0.9 * length(result))
train <- result[1:as.integer(row)]
# train <- sample(train)
x_train <- lapply(train, '[', -length(train[[1]]))
y_train <- lapply(train, '[', length(train[[1]]))
y_train <- unlist(y_train)
test = result[(as.integer(row)+1):length(result)]
x_test <- lapply(test, '[', -length(test[[1]]))
y_test <- lapply(test, '[', length(test[[1]]))

x_train <- array(as.numeric(unlist(x_train)), dim = c(3709, 50, 1))
x_test <- array(as.numeric(unlist(x_test)), dim = c(412, 50, 1))
# x_train <- as.matrix(x_train, dim = c(3709, 51))
# x_test <- as.matrix(x_test, dim = c(412, 51))

class(x_train)

#########################
# Step 2: Build a model #
#########################

library(keras)

model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>% layer_lstm(units = 50L, return_sequences = TRUE, input_shape = list(NULL, 1)) %>%
  layer_dropout(0.2) %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 50L, return_sequences = FALSE) %>%
  layer_dropout(0.2) %>%
  layer_dense(1L) %>%
  layer_activation('linear')
summary(model)

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = 'rmsprop',
  loss = 'mse'
)

###########################
# Step 2: Train the model #
###########################

model %>% fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=512, validation_split = 0.05)


################################
# Step 2: Plot the predictions #
################################

predict_sequences_multiple <- function(model, data, window_size, prediction_len){
  #Predict sequence of 50 steps before shifting prediction run forward by 50 steps
  prediction_seqs = list()
  for (i in 1:as.integer(nrow(data)/prediction_len)){
    curr_frame = array(data[i*prediction_len,,], dim = c(prediction_len,1,1))
    predicted = list()
    for (j in 1:prediction_len){
      predicted[[j]] <- model$predict(curr_frame)[1]
      curr_frame <- curr_frame[2:nrow(curr_frame)]
      curr_frame <- array(c(curr_frame, predicted[[j]]), dim = c(prediction_len,1,1))
    }
    prediction_seqs[[i]] <- unlist(as.numeric(predicted))
  }
  return(prediction_seqs)
}
predictions <- predict_sequences_multiple(model, x_test, 50, 50)
```

you can just run the code to get predicted values (you would need to have keras installed). In the end, I would like to make a graph that look like this:
[image: lstm graph]
As you can see I would like to add predicted values on true data values.
Original Siraj's code in python look like this:

```
def plot_results_multiple(predicted_data, true_data, prediction_len):
    fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(true_data, label='True Data')
    print 'yo'
    #Pad the list of predictions to shift it in the graph to it's correct start
    for i, data in enumerate(predicted_data):
        padding = [None for p in xrange(i * prediction_len)]
        plt.plot(padding + data, label='Prediction')
        plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How can i replicate this graph using ggplot?
My code till now:

```
library(tidyr)
library(rowr)
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- data.frame(y_test = unlist(y_test), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
plot_data <- cbind.fill(plot_data, predictions, fill = NA)
plot_data <- gather(plot_data, key = "key", value = "value")
plot_data <- plot_data %>% dplyr::group_by(key) %>% dplyr::mutate(n = 1:n())


ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = n, y = value, col = key)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: If your question is only about how to generate the chart, as I think it is, then it would be great if you would cut out all the code for generating the forecasts and just post the dataset needed to make the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the shape of your "predictions" object .. But you can try this :

```
fr <- as.data.frame(unlist(predictions))
plot_data <- data.frame(y_test = unlist(y_test), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
plot_data <- cbind.fill(plot_data, fr, fill = NA)
plot_data <- gather(plot_data, key = "key", value = "value")
plot_data <- plot_data %>% dplyr::group_by(key) %>% dplyr::mutate(n = 1:n()) %>% ungroup()
plot_data[plot_data$key!="y_test",] <- plot_data %>% filter(key != "y_test") %>% mutate(key = n %/%50)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = n, y = value, col = key)) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ha found the solution.

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llSourcell/How-to-Predict-Stock-Prices-Easily-Demo/master/sp500.csv"
sp500 <- read.csv(url, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(sp500) <- "closingPrice"

# choose sequence length
seq_length <- 50
sequence_length <- seq_length + 1
result <- list()
for (i in 1:(nrow(sp500) - seq_length)){
  result[[i]] <- sp500[i : (i + seq_length),1]
}

# normalised data
normalised_data <- list()
for (i in 1:length(result)){
  normalised_window <- ((result[[i]] / result[[i]][[1]]) - 1)
  normalised_data[[i]] <- normalised_window
}
result <- normalised_data

# test <- do.call(rbind, result)
# define train and test datasets
row <- round(0.9 * length(result))
train <- result[1:as.integer(row)]
# train <- sample(train)
x_train <- lapply(train, '[', -length(train[[1]]))
y_train <- lapply(train, '[', length(train[[1]]))
y_train <- unlist(y_train)
test = result[(as.integer(row)+1):length(result)]
x_test <- lapply(test, '[', -length(test[[1]]))
y_test <- lapply(test, '[', length(test[[1]]))

# x_train <- array(as.numeric(unlist(x_train)), dim = c(3709, 50, 1))
# x_test <- array(as.numeric(unlist(x_test)), dim = c(412, 50, 1))
x_train <- array_reshape(as.numeric(unlist(x_train)), dim = c(3709, 50, 1))
x_test <- array_reshape(as.numeric(unlist(x_test)), dim = c(412, 50, 1))


#########################
# Step 2: Build a model #
#########################

library(keras)

model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>% layer_lstm(units = 50L, return_sequences = TRUE, input_shape = list(NULL, 1)) %>%
  layer_dropout(0.2) %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 100L, return_sequences = FALSE) %>%
  layer_dropout(0.2) %>%
  layer_dense(1L) %>%
  layer_activation('linear')
summary(model)

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = 'rmsprop',
  loss = 'mse'
)

###########################
# Step 2: Train the model #
###########################

model %>% fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=512, validation_split = 0.05)


################################
# Step 2: Plot the predictions #
################################

predict_sequences_multiple <- function(model, data, window_size, prediction_len){
  #Predict sequence of 50 steps before shifting prediction run forward by 50 steps
  prediction_seqs = list()
  for (i in 1:as.integer(nrow(data)/prediction_len)){
    curr_frame = array(data[i*prediction_len,,], dim = c(1,prediction_len,1))
    predicted = list()
    for (j in 1:prediction_len){
      predicted[[j]] <- predict_on_batch(model, curr_frame)[1]
      curr_frame <- array_reshape(curr_frame[,2:50,], dim = c(1,49,1))
      curr_frame <- array(c(curr_frame, predicted[[j]]), dim = c(1,prediction_len,1))
    }
    prediction_seqs[[i]] <- unlist(as.numeric(predicted))
  }
  return(prediction_seqs)
}
predictions <- predict_sequences_multiple(model, x_test, 50, 50)
predictions <- data.frame(pred = unlist(predictions), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(rowr)
library(dplyr)
library(optmach)

# fr <- as.data.frame(unlist(predictions))
plot_data <- data.frame(y_test = unlist(y_test), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
plot_data <- cbind.fill(plot_data, predictions, fill = NA)
number_of_predictions <- nrow(plot_data) %/% 50
cols <- paste0("Prediction ", 1:number_of_predictions)
help_vector <- c(1, seq(50, number_of_predictions*50, by = 50))
for (i in 1:number_of_predictions){
  if(i == 1){
    plot_data[,cols[i]] <- NA
    plot_data[help_vector[i]:help_vector[i+1],cols[i]] <- c(plot_data[(help_vector[i]):help_vector[i+1],"pred"])
    }else{
      plot_data[,cols[i]] <- NA
      x <- plot_data[help_vector[i]+1,"pred"] - plot_data[help_vector[i]+1,"y_test"]
      plot_data[(help_vector[i]+1):(help_vector[i+1]),cols[i]] <- c(plot_data[(help_vector[i]+1):help_vector[i+1],"pred"]) - x
    }
  }

plot_data[,"pred"] <- NULL
plot_data <- gather(plot_data, key = "key", value = "value")
plot_data <- plot_data %>% dplyr::group_by(key) %>% dplyr::mutate(n = 1:n())

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = n, y = value, col = key)) + geom_line()
```